# Spring form checkbox tag: why generate a hidden element?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for a web application. On a form, I have

```
<form:checkbox path="agreeTerms" id="agreeTerms"/>
```

When the page is rendered, the following HTML is generated

```
<input id="agreeTerms" type="checkbox" value="true" name="agreeTerms">
<input type="hidden" value="on" name="_agreeTerms">
```

Does anyone know the purpose of the hidden tag? What would happen if the hidden input tag is removed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The hidden input tag is to indicate a field that was originally part of the form. When a form is submitted the checkbox input field is only sent if it has a value (i.e. 'checked'). If it's not selected then nothing is sent. The underscore prefixed hidden field is using to indicate that it was part of the form but should be defaulted to "un-checked/false".

You can test this out by creating an HTML form with a checkbox field and submitting it without the field checked.

Also, to see how it's done check out the source code for [WebDataBinder](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/0a8f5b2919ef7193d17b045b3a757800160d64e9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.java#L217):

```
/**
* Check the given property values for field markers,
* i.e. for fields that start with the field marker prefix.
* <p>The existence of a field marker indicates that the specified
* field existed in the form. If the property values do not contain
* a corresponding field value, the field will be considered as empty
* and will be reset appropriately.
* @param mpvs the property values to be bound (can be modified)
* @see #getFieldMarkerPrefix
* @see #getEmptyValue(String, Class)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input!  "If it's not selected then nothing is sent. "? Sent by the browser? Do you mean it is part of HTML specification?

Comment: Yes it's part of the HTML spec. Unchecked values for checkboxes are not sent by the browser to the server upon form submission. The general workaround is to have a hidden field (such as prefixed with "_" like Spring does or suffixed with ".hidden") and check for it's existence to set a value to "unchecked" or "false" on the server side. See step 3 for the W3C form spec for details: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set

Comment: One more question: does it matter to put the hidden input element anywhere on the form?

Comment: Generally no. Form position does not matter for any input element if it has a unique name. If two form elements have the same name then the order they will appear in the submitted form data is dependent on the order they appear in the form.

Comment: you we will end up receiving an `array` of values on server side for `parameters` with same name.

Comment: Really annoying if you are using ajax to serialize the form.

Comment: I have a list of checkboxes (generated by c:forEach), and the hidden input elements for them all have the same name. In the ModelAttribute class that data variable is defined as List<Long>. It works fine, just the hidden INPUT elements break the HTML layout. Is there a way to turn if off? To not be generated?

Comment: @DavidBalažic did you get a way to disable them?