# Spring forms tag checkbox (form:checkbox) hidden field not sent to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have a form that uses JQuery 2.1.3 and Spring MVC 4.1.3.   On the form is a checkbox, which causes Spring to [create a hidden field and add that to my form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368168/spring-form-checkbox-tag-why-generate-a-hidden-element).   This is normal, expected Spring behavior, however, it doesn't appear that the hidden element is getting passed back to the server.   Inspecting the POST in Chrome's developer tools, I can see the checkbox value going back if it's checked, and nothing going back if it's unchecked.   Either way I don't see the value of the hidden field.

I am submitting the form using a JQuery `onclick()` handler and wondered if this might be thwarting the expected behavior somehow, because other than that I can't see any problem.   Here's the code:

JSP source:

```
<form:input id="mycheckboxinput" path="mycheckbox" />
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input id="mycheckboxinput" name="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_mycheckbox" value="on"/>
```

JQuery Submit code:

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm").attr("action", "alternateaction.do");
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be completely unrelated to the checkbox itself.   We were disabling all the controls on the form and then turning the checkbox back on.   Because "all the other controls" included the hidden fields, they were disabled as well, and were not sent to the controller with the POST.    This was breaking the Spring functionality since it needed those fields to work.   So, be careful of that when you're turning fields off and on using Javascript outside of the normal form workflow.