# Can I disable generating hidden field for checkbox tag: in Spring MVC?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Can I disable spring MVC to [generate hidden field for checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368168/spring-form-checkbox-tag-why-generate-a-hidden-element). I'm using Thymeleaf templates.

Thanks!

Comment: Just insert `<input id="name" type="checkbox" value="true" name="name">` manually, and don't use `<form:checkbox/>`

Comment: Unfortunately if you do this you cannot bind the model property to the checkbox. When the model is returned you have to take care of any checkboxes manually

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly old question, but I just ran into this posting a Spring form that contained checkboxes with a GET action. My work-around also uses jQuery, which was not tagged in this question, but it did achieve the desired result.

The _checkbox hidden field was showing in the URL as a query string parameter. I ended up using jQuery to remove the Spring-generated hidden fields at page load, which cleaned up the URL on submit. I did not see any adverse behavior on the server side.